# Java Websocket client lib issue: nv-websocket-client sendBinary

Tags: java, websocket, client

When using sendBinary of this lib from client I got all 0 in the server ;(

this page asks me to to add more description but the code bellow is simple and straight forward and should be self explainable...

client side code:

```
private WebSocket connect() throws IOException, WebSocketException {
    return new WebSocketFactory()
            .setConnectionTimeout(5000)
            .createSocket("ws://localhost:8080/testwsapp2/endpoint")
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                public void onBinaryMessage(WebSocket websocket, byte[] message) {

                    String strmsg = new String(message, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
                    System.out.println("message from server: " + strmsg);

                    //echo back
                    try {
                        strmsg = "echo: " + strmsg;
                        System.out.println("now echo back with \"" + strmsg + "\"");

                        byte[] bytemsg = strmsg.getBytes("US-ASCII");
                        System.out.println("echo message length = " + bytemsg.length);

                        String a2sview = Arrays.toString(bytemsg);
                        System.out.println("echo message a2sview: " + a2sview);

                        websocket.sendBinary(bytemsg);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            })
            .addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE)
            .connect();
}
```

server side code:

```
@OnOpen
public void on_open(Session session) {
    try {
        byte[] bytemsg = ("hello client").getBytes("US-ASCII");
        session.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytemsg));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@OnMessage
public void on_message(Session session, ByteBuffer message) {

    byte[] bytemsg = new byte[message.remaining()];
    System.out.println("client message length = " + bytemsg.length);

    String a2sview = Arrays.toString(bytemsg);
    System.out.println("client message a2sview: " + a2sview);

    String strmsg = new String(bytemsg, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    System.out.println("client message: " + strmsg);

}
```

client output:

```
message from server: hello client
now echo back with "echo: hello client"
echo message length = 18
echo message a2sview: [101, 99, 104, 111, 58, 32, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116]
```

server output

```
Info:   client message length = 18
Info:   client message a2sview: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Info:   client message:
```

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: I git-cloned the nv-websocket-client source code and very suspect the operation "int b = (payload[i] ^ maskingKey[i % 4]) & 0xFF;" at line 136 of WebSocketOutputStream.java. Any one can help and inspect?

Comment: I got an email response from Takahiko Kawasaki himself with a test code and all fine when testing using ws://echo.websocket.org. So there must be something wrong with the code on the server side. P.S. server=glassfish4.1.1, platform=centos7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server-side `on_message` method, you have to copy the content of `message` to `bytemsg` before you pass `bytemsg` to `Array.toString`.

```java
byte[] bytemsg = new byte[message.remaining()];
System.out.println("client message length = " + bytemsg.length);

// !!! Copy the content of 'message' to 'bytemsg' here !!!

String a2sview = Arrays.toString(bytemsg);
System.out.println("client message a2sview: " + a2sview);
```

Comment: Thank you very much again Takahiko. You are right it worked ;-) I really should read original Java doc in more detail but now I just want to make things done in a rush. Appreciate you previous email and answer here.